# Error Running composer.phar update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

This worked about 3 months ago, which was the last time I edited this JSON file. The change at the time was to add the reference to `ThirdEngine/DotNetIntegration` which is a library I wrote. Running php `composer.phar` update gives me the following error.

Problem 1

> Installation request for doctrine/migrations dev-master -> satisfiable
>   by doctrine/migrations[dev-master].
>
> doctrine/migrations dev-master requires symfony/console ~2.3 -> no
>   matching package found.

Problem 2

> doctrine/migrations 1.0.x-dev requires symfony/console ~2.3 -> no
>   matching package found.
>
> doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master requires
>   doctrine/migrations ~1.0 -> satisfiable by
>   doctrine/migrations[1.0.x-dev].
>
> Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
>   dev-master -> satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[dev-master].

```html
{
  "name": "latent-codex/estimator",
  "description": "",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "propel/propel-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "braintree/braintree_php" : "2.27.0",
    "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "1.2.*",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.*",
    "intervention/image": "2.*",
    "robmorgan/phinx": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
    "ThirdEngine/DotNetIntegration": "dev-master",
    "symfony/process": "2.2.*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "3d9b33f82636944b2cf643e5bf4011c2a89af6b4"
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "alpha",
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git://github.com/ThirdEngine/DotNetIntegration.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Since you are only adding a new lib you can use `php composer.phar update ThirdEngine/DotNetIntegration`. Symfony 2.2 is EOL and you are trying to update all the packages set to dev master so you may encounter dependency issues

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just upgrading the frameworks to newer versions and setting the versions in the composer.json to fixed version properly like it should have been done originally.